# Redirect to different page if already opened before

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I've created a login/signup system and have it if when you go to the homepage straight away it'll redirect you to the login page etc. But I'm trying to create an intro/tutorial stage when you signup and login for the first time. I can't figure out how to do it since I'm pretty much a noob at this sort of thing. I need help to be quite in-depth as well since I already stated I'm a noob at this thing, but any help you give is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

### I've tried searching around to find something like this but I've found no results in depth enough for me.

Start of login.php:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect to homepage
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: ../get-started/");
    exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "secure/data/accounts.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
```

Redirect user to tutorial page (mandatory at the moment):

```
                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            

                            // Redirect user
                            header("location: ../get-started/");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

---

I'm hoping to have a part where it checks if you have already seen the tutorial page before, and if you have it will redirect you straight to the home page.

I currently just have it to just go straight to the tutorial page as I have no clue how to set it up.

Comment: You can use cookies for instance. Basic cookie information: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp , or have the database store a boolean value in a field named "visited" or something and build your logic around that.

Comment: you can use various storage mechanisms to achieve what you need. For example 1 DB set a value in DB table of user `first_login` and do tutorial if it is true, afterwrads set to false. 2. SESSION set the user session with some variable if first login. 3. COOKIES set a cookie first_login and do tutorial and unset afterwards. Option 1 is recomended as it can handle truly once the tutorial as needed

Comment: *"I'm hoping to have a part where it checks if you have already seen the tutorial page"* - Sounds reasonable, have you tried anything?  Decompose the problem into individual steps.  Pick a step.  What did you try for implementing that step?  If you decompose the problem into small enough steps you're likely to find that you have the tools in front of you to implement each one.  So, other than a heavy reliance on the word "noob", what exactly is stopping you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, in the end, I am using a system to add a cookie for the first time you visit it. Then each time you visit it, if you have the cookie it gave you it will redirect you to the main homepage.

I explained it in a messy way but I'm sure you get point. And to the people that commented, thanks for commenting to help me out! I have provided an example of the code I used below:

Example:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['tutorial']))
{
    setcookie("tutorial", "no");
    header('Location: example-intro.php');
    exit();
}
else
{
    header('Location: example-home.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```